# Testing XML data for being midweek or weekend with XSLT-1?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Take the following XML sample:

```
<Meeting BookmarkId="0" PageBreak="0" NumberClasses="1" SpecialEvent="1">
    <Date ThisWeek="W20200406" NextWeek="W20200413">April 6-12</Date>
    <SpecialEvent>
        <Event>Memorial</Event>
        <Location>Address goes here</Location>
        <Date Day="7" DayShort="Tue" DayFull="Tuesday" Month="4" MonthShort="Apr" MonthFull="April" Year="2020">07/04/2020</Date>
    </SpecialEvent>
</Meeting>
```

Bear in mind that this XML content is automatically created for about 50 languages so the locales used for the days of the week differ obviously.

Is it possible using XSLT-1 to programatically determine if the date is midweek or weekend (irrespective of the locale of the data)?

If needs must I will change the logic of my applicate that creates the XML to include a new boolean attribute stating if it is midweek or weekend. But I wanted to know if it was easy to text for with a XSL `if` condition.

Comment: It is possible - though not easy - to calculate the day of week from the date itself (i.e. from the Day, Month and Year attributes). However, it is not clear what is "midweek" and what is "weekend" - esp. when you say you are dealing with diverse locales.

Comment: @michael.hor257k midweek - Monday to Friday; weekend - Saturday and Sunday

Comment: @michael.hor257k If it is too difficult, or the locales bring in added complexity, then maybe just programatically adding a new attribute will be the easiest way forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SpecialEvent/Date">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="day-of-week">
            <xsl:call-template name="day-of-week">
                <xsl:with-param name="year" select="@Year"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="month" select="@Month"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="day" select="@Day"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:attribute name="Weekend">
            <xsl:value-of select="$day-of-week &lt; 2"/>    
        </xsl:attribute>        
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="day-of-week">
    <!-- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence -->
    <xsl:param name="year" />
    <xsl:param name="month"/>
    <xsl:param name="day"/>
    <!-- m is the month (3 = March, 4 = April, 5 = May, ..., 14 = February) -->
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="$month &lt; 3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="K" select="$y mod 100"/>
    <xsl:variable name="J" select="floor($y div 100)"/>
    <!--  h is the day of the week (0 = Saturday, 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ..., 6 = Friday) -->
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="($day + floor(13*($m + 1) div 5) + $K + floor($K div 4) + floor($J div 4) - 2*$J) mod 7"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$h"/> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

> how I might tweak it to see Monday as the 1st day of the week and Sunday as the 7th

You could simply shift the result before outputting it. Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$h"/>
```

make the template output:

```
<xsl:value-of select="($h + 5) mod 7 + 1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I made some tweaks for testing the core `day-of-week` template you provided and it works. Thanks.

Comment: This is a very useful template. Could you indicate how I might tweak it to see Monday as the 1st day of the week and Sunday as the 7th please. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisGilbert See the addition to my answer.